# How to get NeurophStudio Samples

Tags: neural-network

I've Neuroph Studio 2.85. But there is no Neuron samples project. Where are they? To see them is there any need to have java Virtual Machine. Please tell me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you visit the FAQ section of [Neuroph Studio](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/faq.html) it clearly states

```
2. What are the requirements for Neuroph? 

 To use Neuroph you just need to have Java 1.6
```

Get Java from the [official website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

**Update:**

As per the OP's comment below, samples are available in Neuroph Studio 2.6 but not in 2.8

Comment: plzz try to understand....no neuron samples are seen. I've no samples project when I click File > New Project. What is the problem & I've java 7..isn't enough?

Comment: @SaifaLiza If the java is properly installed in your system and the java path is also set, then try re installing Neuroph Studio.

Comment: Got it!!! but not in 2.8, it is Neuroph Studio 2.6. Samples are in 2.6 but not in 2.8. Thank you pss

Comment: If the answer was useful then please accept it by clicking on the tick mark on the left side. Else you can write your own answer and accept it. This helps other users in the future.